# How would I use the Find function in VBA to get the address of a cell that I can use to SetSource some chart data?

Tags: excel, vba, find, excel-charts

I'm pretty new to VBA, so apologies if my code is a bit messy. I'm having a bit of trouble with using **Find** to get a cell address back. I want to find the row of cells based on the listbox value, and then find the address for the first cell of relevant data (in my case, C6) and the last cell of relevant data (in my case, L6).

I would then like to concatenate these two cells together so I can create a range (C6:C12). I'd then like to use the information to create a source for a constantly updating chart based on the listbox value.

I'm pretty sure that the issue is with how I find the address in the first place. Whenever I attempt to run it, the run-time error '91 "Object variable or with block variable not set" shows up.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub lstCityWA_Click()

'Denote variables that will be used to get the label data for the header of the sheet
Dim strCity As String, wsWAData As Worksheet, strWA As String
'Denote variables that will be used to create the chart
Dim chtCrimeData As ChartObject
'Denote variables that will be used to source the chart data
Dim rngAddress1 As Range, rngAddress2 As Range, rngChartData1 As Range, rngChartData2 As Range
'Denote variables that will be used for the imagebox
Dim picPath As String

'Create the VLOOKUP that will change the header label caption
Set wsWAData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Washington Data")

strCity = lstCityWA.Value

strWA = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strCity, Worksheets("Washington Data").Range("A6:A187"), 1, False)

lblWA.Caption = strWA

'Find the cells that make up the beginning and end of the row needed for chart data
Set rngAddress1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Washington Data").Range("A6:A187").Find(what:=strCity, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

rngChartData1.Value = rngAddress1.Offset(, 3).Value

Set rngAddress2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Washington Data").Range("A6:A187").Find(what:=strCity, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

rngChartData2.Value = rngAddress2.Offset(, 12).Value

'Create the chart
Set chtCrimeData = Worksheets("Washington").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=180, Width:=300, Top:=7, Height:=200)


'Concatenate the data to set the source for the chart
chtCrimeData.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Washington Data").Range(rngChartData1 & ":" & rngChartData2)

'Put the photo of the town in the image box
picPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Pictures\Washington\Cities\" & strCity & ".jpg"
imgWA.Picture = LoadPicture(picPath)

End Sub
```

Comment: That means the `Find` was not successful.

Comment: The problem is that your code references too many data. No one here can test it. That same problem interferes with your own progress. To find a row or a cell address can be delegated to a very small function which you can construct quickly, test thoroughly, ask about if need be, and only install in your main code if that simplifies the code. Worksheet function VLOOKUP will return a value, MATCH will return an address. In VBA you have the `Find` method which returns  a cell giving you both Value and Address. There should be no `imgWA.Picture = LoadPicture(picPath)` in any question about that.

Comment: You havent passed a range to 'rngChartData1' and to 'rngChartData2'(you haven't used Set yet). If the data in range "A6:A187" are formulas, you have to use 'xlFormulas' instead of 'xlValues'. The find method has a SearchDirection parameter which is xlNext by default i.e. the first cell to be evaluated  will be cell A7 and not A6.

Comment: Okay thank you for all the help! I'll be sure to set the ranges next time and I'll separate it into smaller functions.